# Proof of Morse inequalities?

Tags: manifolds, homology-cohomology, morse-theory, cw-complexes

Can you think of a proof of Morse inequalities  without using the Morse cohom. $\cong$ sing.cohom or Witten's approach?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory#The_Morse_inequalities

Any references will do

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is very classical of course. The classical proof of the Morse inequalities goes through the study of half spaces $f_c=\{x\in M\,|\,f(x)<c\}$. Passing a critical value (assuming that all critical points have different values) attaches a $k$-handle (or $k$-cell if you like CW-complexes) to the sublevel set. This is worked out in detail in Milnor's Morse theory, or Banayaga and Hurtubise's Lectures on Morse homology (this does not use Morse homology).